# Elasricsearch and Solr Data Visualization Tools

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, kibana, banana

Are there any other data visualization tools for Elasticsearch other than Kibana? Similar question for Solr and Banana.

can someone please comment on the pros and cons of any such tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucid work Release Updated Version For Solr couple of weeks Back called SILK.
you can find out more about it here: https://github.com/LucidWorks/silk